# Send Print Command from Xamarin.Android to bluetooth printer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

So I am pretty new to Xamarin.Android, I have managed to connect to my Bluetooth printer device using the code below, so now I want to send a print command to the printer but I have not been able to for several weeks now. Searched the internet but I have not been able to find a solution. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

```
Button btnConnect;
TextView txtView;
Button btnPrint;

BluetoothSocket socket;
BluetoothAdapter adapter;
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
private byte[] buffer;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.BrianPeek);
    FindViews();
    HandleEvents();
    buffer = new byte[1024];
}

private void HandleEvents()
{
    btnConnect.Click += BtnConnect_Click;
    btnPrint.Click += Print_Click;
}

private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variables
    string ipAddress = "192.168.1.100";
    int portNumber = 9100;
    List<string> myText = new List<string>() { "Line1", "Line2" };

    // Try to find the platform specific services
    // var printer = DependencyService.Get<DSInterfaces.IPrinter>();
    var printer = new Printer();
    if (printer == null) {
         // Do not proceed if no services found for the platform
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetTitle("Printer");
         alert.SetMessage("Error");
         alert.Show();
     }

     try
     {
         // Call themethod, declare by the IPrinter interface
         printer.Print(ipAddress, portNumber, myText);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetTitle("Printer");
         alert.SetMessage("Failed to print redemption slip\nReason "+ex.Message);
         alert.Show();

         // Exception here could mean difficulties in connecting to the printer etc
         //await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Failed to print redemption slip\nReason: {ex.Message}", "OK");
     }
 }

 private async void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

     if(adapter == null) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetTitle("Bluetooth");
         alert.SetMessage("No Bluetooth Adapter Found");
         alert.Show();
     }

     if (!adapter.IsEnabled) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetTitle("Bluetooth");
         alert.SetMessage("Bluetooth Adapter is not set!");
         alert.Show();
     }

     bluetoothDevice = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices
         where bd.Name == "MTP-II"
         select bd).FirstOrDefault();

     if (bluetoothDevice != null) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetTitle("Bluetooth");
         alert.SetMessage("Bluetooth device " + bluetoothDevice.Name );
         alert.Show();

         //Connect Bluetooth Device 
         socket = bluetoothDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
         await socket.ConnectAsync();

         //after connection, communication occurs through input and output stream
         // Read data from the device
         await socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

         // Write data to the device
         await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

     } else {
          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          alert.SetTitle("Bluetooth");
          alert.SetMessage("The device is not found");
          alert.Show();
     }           
}

private void FindViews()
{
      btnConnect = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnectBlue);
      txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtText);
      btnPrint = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConnectPrint);
}
```

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/@frankiefoo/xamarin-forms-how-to-print-receipts-using-ecs-pos-printers-488da61e3c84) and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20244/print-receipt-via-pos-printer)

Comment: Thank you so much, it has worked.